# I am getting an 501 error from maven repo

Tags: java, spring, eclipse, maven, junit

I am trying to build the build.xml

But when it reaches

It throws this error.

I have deleted the .m2 folder and rerun, still getting this error. I believe there is an internal call for a http link to get org.junit:junit-bom:pom:5.9.1, can we override that or something.

it is saying Unable to download the artifact from any repository, but when I hit "http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/junit/junit-bom/5.7.1/junit-bom-5.7.1.pom" from that machine causing the error I got the below,

501 HTTPS Required.
Use https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/
More information at https://links.sonatype.com/central/501-https-required

So why it is not redirecting the URL to the https link, or how I can force that

Full Error log:

```
[artifact:dependencies] Downloading: org/junit/junit-bom/5.9.1/junit-bom-5.9.1.pom from repository central at http://repo1.maven.org/maven2
[artifact:dependencies] Error transferring file: Server returned HTTP response code: 501 for URL: http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/junit/junit-bom/5.9.1/junit-bom-5.9.1.pom
[artifact:dependencies] [WARNING] Unable to get resource 'org.junit:junit-bom:pom:5.9.1' from repository central (http://repo1.maven.org/maven2): Error transferring file: Server returned HTTP response code: 501 for URL: http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/junit/junit-bom/5.9.1/junit-bom-5.9.1.pom
[artifact:dependencies] An error has occurred while processing the Maven artifact tasks.
[artifact:dependencies]  Diagnosis:
[artifact:dependencies] 
[artifact:dependencies] Unable to resolve artifact: Unable to get dependency information: Unable to read the metadata file for artifact 'org.apache.commons:commons-text:jar': POM 'org.junit:junit-bom' not found in repository: Unable to download the artifact from any repository
[artifact:dependencies] 
[artifact:dependencies]   org.junit:junit-bom:pom:5.9.1
[artifact:dependencies] 
[artifact:dependencies] from the specified remote repositories:
[artifact:dependencies]   central (http://repo1.maven.org/maven2),
[artifact:dependencies]   apache.snapshots (https://repository.apache.org/snapshots)
[artifact:dependencies] 
[artifact:dependencies]  for project org.junit:junit-bom
[artifact:dependencies]   org.apache.commons:commons-text:jar:1.10.0
[artifact:dependencies] 
[artifact:dependencies] from the specified remote repositories:
[artifact:dependencies]   RemoteRepo (https://repo1.maven.org/maven2),
[artifact:dependencies]   central-https (https://repo1.maven.org/maven2)
[artifact:dependencies] 
[artifact:dependencies] Path to dependency: 
[artifact:dependencies]     1) org.apache.maven:super-pom:pom:2.0
[artifact:dependencies] 
[artifact:dependencies] 
[artifact:dependencies] 

BUILD FAILED
D:\x\y\build.xml:63: Unable to resolve artifact: Unable to get dependency information: Unable to read the metadata file for artifact 'org.apache.commons:commons-text:jar': POM 'org.junit:junit-bom' not found in repository: Unable to download the artifact from any repository

  org.junit:junit-bom:pom:5.9.1

from the specified remote repositories:
  central (http://repo1.maven.org/maven2),
  apache.snapshots (https://repository.apache.org/snapshots)

 for project org.junit:junit-bom
  org.apache.commons:commons-text:jar:1.10.0

from the specified remote repositories:
  RemoteRepo (https://repo1.maven.org/maven2),
  central-https (https://repo1.maven.org/maven2)

Path to dependency: 
    1) org.apache.maven:super-pom:pom:2.0



Total time: 1 second
```

Answer (score 0):

As the reference https://links.sonatype.com/central/501-https-required says:

**Replace** http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/ with https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/

**Replace** http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/ with https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/

Comment: I am using <artifact:remoteRepository id="RemoteRepo" url="https://repo1.maven.org/maven2" /> not the http

Comment: go the same error using https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/

Comment: Are you sure your setting is not overridden from settings.xml or something else?

Comment: settings.xml is also using the https.

<mirror>
   <id>central-https</id>
   <name>Maven Repository</name>
   <url>https://repo1.maven.org/maven2</url>
   <mirrorOf>central</mirrorOf>
  </mirror>